# Pandas calculating column based on inter-dependent lagged values

Tags: list, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. The rightmost two columns are my desired columns:

```
Open    Close   open_to_close   close_to_next_open  open_desired    close_desired
0          0       0                  3             0                  0
0          0       4                  8             3                  7
0          0       1                  1            15                 16
```

The calculations are as the following:

```
open_desired = close_desired(prior row) + close_to_next_open(prior row)
close_desired = open_desired + open_to_close
```

How do I implement the following in a loop manner? I am trying to do this until the last row.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'open': [0,0,0], 'close': [0,0,0], 'open_to_close': [0,4,1], 'close_to_next_open': [3,8,1]}) 
 df['close_desired'] = 0 
 df['open_desired'] = 0
 ##First step is to create open_desired in current row which is dependent on close_desired in previous row
 df['open_desired'] = df['close_desired'].shift() + df['close_to_next_open'].shift()
 ##second step is to create close_desired in current row which is dependent on open_desired in current row
 df['close_desired'] = df['open_desired'] + df['open_to_close']
 df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I found two problems. You need to initialize the column "close_desired", and on the second line of code you have a typo ("closed" should be "close"). Do a ````df.fillna(0,inplace=True)```` at the end.

Comment: @xyzjayne thank you, made the second line edit. I am new to python. How do I initialize "close_desired"?

Comment: ````df['close_desired'] = 0````

Comment: @xyzjayne thank you for the help. Added `df.fillna(0,inplace=True)`. What is that line doing?

Comment: Without the line, df has two NaN entries on the first row because shift() produces NaN values for the first row. fillna replaces NaN with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is with `iterrows()`

```
for row, v in df.iterrows():
    if row>0:
        df.loc[row,'open_desired'] = df.shift(1).loc[row, 'close_desired'] + df.shift(1).loc[row, 'close_to_next_open']
        df.loc[row,'close_desired'] = df.loc[row, 'open_desired'] + df.loc[row, 'open_to_close']
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! What is `if row>0` doing in the loop?

Comment: it's avoiding the first row becuase it would write a NaN which would get carried over and render all values as NaN

Comment: It worked for me. Waiting a little more before accepting this answer as to not dissuade other users from answering.